# Android : Where to put intent in Login page

Tags: android, android-intent

I am working on Android studio.Below is an auto generated Login page from where i want to put intent to start a new activity.Please guide me where should i use this intent in the above Login page,this is first android app i m trying to create.I want to create the intent when the button is clicked.
*** And Can we create an intent only inside the onCreate() method ? ***

```
 /**
 * A login screen that offers login via email/password.
 */
  public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

  /**
 * Id to identity READ_CONTACTS permission request.
 */
private static final int REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 0;

/**
 * A dummy authentication store containing known user names and passwords.
 * TODO: remove after connecting to a real authentication system.
 */
private static final String[] DUMMY_CREDENTIALS = new String[]{
        "foo@example.com:hello", "bar@example.com:world"
};
/**
 * Keep track of the login task to ensure we can cancel it if requested.
 */
private UserLoginTask mAuthTask = null;

// UI references.
private AutoCompleteTextView mEmailView;
private EditText mPasswordView;
private View mProgressView;
private View mLoginFormView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.login_logo);
    // Set up the login form.
    mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    populateAutoComplete();

    mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (id == R.id.password|| id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                attemptLogin();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    Button mEmailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
    mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            attemptLogin();
        }
    });

    mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
    mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);
}

private void populateAutoComplete() {
    if (!mayRequestContacts()) {
        return;
    }

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}

private boolean mayRequestContacts() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        return true;
    }
    if (checkSelfPermission(READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    }
    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(READ_CONTACTS)) {
        Snackbar.make(mEmailView, R.string.permission_rationale, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction(android.R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
                    }
                });
    } else {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
 */
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
        if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            populateAutoComplete();
        }
    }
}


/**
 * Attempts to sign in or register the account specified by the login form.
 * If there are form errors (invalid email, missing fields, etc.), the
 * errors are presented and no actual login attempt is made.
 */
private void attemptLogin() {
    if (mAuthTask != null) {
        return;
    }

    // Reset errors.
    mEmailView.setError(null);
    mPasswordView.setError(null);

    // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
    String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
    String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

    boolean cancel = false;
    View focusView = null;

    // Check for a valid password, if the user entered one.
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && !isPasswordValid(password)) {
        mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
        focusView = mPasswordView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    // Check for a valid email address.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    } else if (!isEmailValid(email)) {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    if (cancel) {
        // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
        // form field with an error.
        focusView.requestFocus();
    } else {
        // Show a progress spinner, and kick off a background task to
        // perform the user login attempt.
        showProgress(true);
        mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask(email, password);
        mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
    }
}

private boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
    //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
    return email.contains("@");
}

private boolean isPasswordValid(String password) {
    //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
    return password.length() > 4;
}

/**
 * Shows the progress UI and hides the login form.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
private void showProgress(final boolean show) {
    // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
    // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
    // the progress spinner.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        mLoginFormView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                show ? 0 : 1).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        mProgressView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                show ? 1 : 0).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            }
        });
    } else {
        // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
        // and hide the relevant UI components.
        mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
    return new CursorLoader(this,
            // Retrieve data rows for the device user's 'profile' contact.
            Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY), ProfileQuery.PROJECTION,

            // Select only email addresses.
            ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE +
                    " = ?", new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email
            .CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE},

            // Show primary email addresses first. Note that there won't be
            // a primary email address if the user hasn't specified one.
            ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.IS_PRIMARY + " DESC");
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
    List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        emails.add(cursor.getString(ProfileQuery.ADDRESS));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    addEmailsToAutoComplete(emails);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {

}

private void addEmailsToAutoComplete(List<String> emailAddressCollection) {
    //Create adapter to tell the AutoCompleteTextView what to show in its dropdown list.
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<>(Login.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, emailAddressCollection);

    mEmailView.setAdapter(adapter);
}


private interface ProfileQuery {
    String[] PROJECTION = {
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.IS_PRIMARY,
    };

    int ADDRESS = 0;
    int IS_PRIMARY = 1;
}

/**
 * Represents an asynchronous login/registration task used to authenticate
 * the user.
 */
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private final String mEmail;
    private final String mPassword;

    UserLoginTask(String email, String password) {
        mEmail = email;
        mPassword = password;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

        try {
            // Simulate network access.
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return false;
        }

        for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
            String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
            if (pieces[0].equals(mEmail)) {
                // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
                return pieces[1].equals(mPassword);
            }
        }

        // TODO: register the new account here.
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);

        if (success) {

            if (mEmailView.getText().toString().equals("admin@gmail") && mPasswordView.getText().toString().equals("admin123")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logged In Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent("csimplifyit.mobileapp.myschool.login.Menu");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            //finish();
        } else {
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
            mPasswordView.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);
    }
}
```

}

Here is the intent i want to use in this auto generated Login(android studio).

```
 if (mEmailView.getText().toString().equals("admin@gmail.com") && mPasswordView.getText().toString().equals("admin123")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logged In Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent("csimplifyit.mobileapp.myschool.login.Menu");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

Comment: when u want to launch the intent? Be specific.

Comment: Please be elaborate what you want  ?

Comment: @Rob, I see that you already added the startActivity to the onPostExecute. So what is your question? If it doesn't work as you expect, then add the description of the problem to the question: what do you expect, what do you see instead. If there are errors include the full error log and indicate the relevant lines in the source code,

Answer (score 0):

Flow should be like this:

1. Splash screen(Fraction of seconds)
2. Login Page (on success call HomeScreen Activity)
3. HomeScreen Activity

If you do not want to ask user login every time on app launch then keep user data in **shared preferences** like userId. On splash screen check userId empty or not if Empty then Navigate to HomeScreen or LoginScreen.